# Quicker way to instantiate and fill array of objects

Tags: javascript

Is there a cleaner/nicer/quicker way to do this?

```
taskList = new Array();
currentTask = new Object();
closedTask = new Object();
search = new Object();
taskList.push(currentTask); 
taskList.push(closedTask); 
taskList.push(search);
```

Comment: taskList =[{},{},{}]; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, if you're not using currentTask, closedTask and search anywhere else you can do:

```
var taskList = [ {}, {}, {} ];
```

Otherwise:

```
var currentTask = {},
    closedTask = {},
    search = {};
var taskList = [ currentTask, closedTask, search];
```

Comment: Please note that `tasklist` is not a property in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentTask = {},
    closedTask = {},
    search = {},
    taskList = [currentTask, closedTask, search];
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of these methods work, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

```
var taskList = [{}, {}, {}] //Creates 3 Objects
OR
var taskList = [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()] //Object() can be replaced with any other object such as Array, String, etc
```

You can then just access the individual objects using:

```
taskList[x]; //Where x is the index of the object.
```

Answer (score 2):

An even nerdier variant :

```
var currentTask,
    closedTask, 
    search,
    taskList = [currentTask={}, closedTask={}, search={}];
```

Joke aside, using the initializers syntax,
`{}` is basically equivalent to `new Object` and `[]` to `new Array`.

The braces syntax allows to create **untyped** objects (i.e. objects of the generic `Object` class), while the `new` operator allows to create class instances.

If you want to create an empty, untyped object, the result is equivalent.

Now consider this:

```
var Dog = function (value)
{
   this.bone= value;
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function () { console.log ("Woof!"); }

var Alf = new Dog (10); // Alf is a true able dog
var Rex = { bone:10 };  // Rex is just a generic object aping a dog

console.log (Alf.bone); // 10
console.log (Rex.bone); // 10
Alf.bark();             // Woof!
Rex.bark();             // generic objects don't bark !
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the "initializers syntax" is `new Object(), new Array()` or just the brackets/curly brackets?

Comment: _"basically"_? Nope. It _is_ equivalent, even.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well nitpickers might object that a `{}` or `[]` initializer is not gramatically the same thing as the invokation of the new operator, but yes, for all practical purposes it is.

Comment: `new object()` and `{}` are both initializers with a different syntax :). See my edit

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
taskList=[currentTask,closedTask,search];
```